# Shell Script - read two lines of file and read one line of another file

Tags: shell

Say, I have two files.

File1 contains:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
line7
line8
line9
line10
```

and File2 contains:

```
anotherline1
anotherline2
anotherline3
```

I want to do a while loop so that it outputs this into a File3:

```
line1
line2
anotherline1
line3
line4
anotherline2
line5
line6
anotherline3
line7
line8
anotherline1
line9
line10
anotherline2
```

I've searched here for an answer but I can't figure out how to do it.
I must say I'm pretty noob at shell scripting...

Also: The "while loop" should be until reaching end of file1. Doesn't matter how long is File2, actually, in my personal scenario, File2 will always be shorter than File1. Output should be: File1Line1, File1Line2, File2Line1, File1Line3, File1Line4, File2Line2.... etc

Any help?

note: if this was already answered before, then mods please close this question. I just couldn't find any answers after googling for some hours.

EDIT: Added clarification of when to end the loop.

Comment: BTW -- how do you want this to behave if the number of lines in the two input files don't match (one line in file2 for every two lines in file1)?

Comment: The "while loop" should be until reaching end of file1. Doesn't matter how long is File2, actually, in my personal scenario, File2 will always be shorter than File1. Output should be: File1Line1, File1Line2, File2Line1, File1Line3, File1Line4, File2Line2.... etc

Comment: You might consider editing that into your question; it significantly changes what constitutes a correct answer.

Comment: After we hit the end of file2, should there be blanks for the lines that would otherwise come from it, or should they just be left out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm interpreting your question correctly, you want to

1. step through `file1` start to finish, and
2. insert the "next" line from `file2` after every two lines, rotating back to the top of `file2` whenever you run out of content.

If that's the goal, you could do it with awk in a number of ways, but the following shell snippet would probably do.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

mapfile -t file2 < file2

max=${#file2[@]}

while read line; do
  ((count++))
  echo "$line"
  if [[ $((count%2)) == 0 ]]; then
    if [[ next -ge max ]]; then
      next=0
    fi
    echo "${file2[next++]}"
  fi
done < file1
```

This has the down side of loading all of `file2` into memory as an array.  If that's a problem because the file is too big, you can perhaps add some shell glop to go find specific lines at each invocation of the loop, though that will be very slow.  Better yet, define your problem more specifically, or consider alternate tools!  :-)

Note also that the `mapfile` command is a bash-4-ism, so if you're on an older Linux, or OSX (which still ships with bash 3), you'll need a different solution ... or an upgrade to bash.

Comment: Where do you get the "rotating back" behavior? I don't see any specification at all (other than that the program must not exit at that point).

Comment: Might consider explicitly specifying the need for bash 4.x here, given use of `mapfile`.

Comment: (BTW, there _are_ easy ways to reopen file2 on hitting its end; one could `read <&3 || { exec 3<file2 && read <&3; }`, for instance).

Comment: THIS !!!

This worked just as I wanted to. I really apology if I made my question too complicated. But this definitely solved it. THANK YOU!!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, great point about bash 4 - I've modified this answer. Regarding "easy ways", I would argue that multiple file handles are a more advanced scripting feature than arrays, and might therefore not be "easier" for someone not already familiar with their use. Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a convenient way to do something that specific in pure shell script.  You're probably better off just writing a python/perl/etc. script.  Something like this awk script would work, but it's somewhat messy:

```
awk '{
  print; getline; print; 
  if (!getline < "file2") { 
    close("file2");
    getline < "file2"
  };
  print
}' file1
```

The `print; getline; print` will print the next line from file1, get the line after that, and then print it.  The `if (!getline < "file2")` tries to read the next line from file2, and if it fails, closes it, implicitly reopens it, and reads the first line from file2.  The final `print` will print that line from file2 (next or first).

Comment: An explanation of how your one-liner works would be highly educational!  :-)

Comment: So, if I add
> file3
at the end, the output would be what I want? I'll try that now...

Comment: (To be clear, the only thing I object to here is the claim that this can't be done in pure shell -- see my answer for a counterexample -- it's otherwise perfectly fine).

Comment: @ghoti Added an explanation.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Indeed, I've upvoted your answer since I like that use of file descriptors (and adjusted my answer to indicate my ignorance).

Comment: This is much easier to read now.  I like the simple logic of this answer. Upvoted.  :)

Answer (score 2):

This awk should work:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[++i]=$0; next} FNR%2{p=$0; curr=(FNR==1 || curr==i) ? 1 : curr+1; next}
    {print p ORS $0 ORS a[curr]}' file2 file1
line1
line2
anotherline1
line3
line4
anotherline2
line5
line6
anotherline3
line7
line8
anotherline1
line9
line10
anotherline2
```

**EDIT:** Even shorter `awk` (thanks to [@geirha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1524545/geirha)):

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[n++]=$0;next}1;!(FNR%2){print a[i++%n]}' file2 file1
```

Comment: Here's a golfed version, for fun `awk 'FNR==NR{a[n++]=$0;next}1;!(FNR%2){print a[i++%n]}' file2 file1`

Comment: Wow that is even better (added in answer).

Answer (score 1):

Easily done in native shell -- no external tools such as `awk` needed. Open two file descriptors, tied to different files, and iterate over both.

```
while :; do
  read -r line1 <&3 && printf '%s\n' "$line1" || break
  read -r line2 <&3 && printf '%s\n' "$line2" || break
  read -r line3 <&4 || { exec 4<file2 && read -r line3 <&4; }
  printf '%s\n' "$line3"
done 3<file1 4<file2 1>file3
```

In this case, `3` is the file descriptor number on which we opened `file1`, and `4` is the file descriptor number on which we opened `file2`. `1>file3`, or simply `>file3`, reroutes output on file descriptor `1` (aka stdout) to the output file.

You could pick other numbers if you liked, though only the range between 3-9 is guaranteed to be free for use on all POSIX shells. (0-2 are stdin, stdout and stderr; above 10 may be used by the shell for its own use, though this is rarely the case in newer and more modern shells).

Comment: This (first example) is pretty much what I wanted. Though the while ends also if reaches end of File2, and I want it to keep it going until all lines of File1 are read.

Comment: Keep going and do what? Add empty lines where content from file2 would otherwise be? Just add more lines from file1?

Comment: First example modified to ignore EOF on file2.

Comment: @user3246010, Ahh. Had to reread the question a bit to gather that you wanted to start file2 over from the top. Specifying that in English rather than only by example would have been appreciated.